# How can I access MySQL via the command line for EasyPHP DevServer

Tags: mysql, command, line, easyphp

I am using a book and its example uses a different program.

Basically I have this entered:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin -u root
```

And I get this error:

```
"'EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

I've looked around online and haven't found many things, the things I did find require some tinkering around and I don't want to mess something up by accident.. to be honest I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing here. I mean I know the basics of the command line but I don't know how to use it for mySQL. So could someone please assist me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have missed to write **mysql** after ".....\bin".

 You should try as following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin\mysql -u root
```

Or 
 add **C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin** to **path** environment variable and just use command like bellow:

```
mysql -u root
```